# Print odd numbers in a given range in python

Tags: python

I've printed odd numbers in a range but i am unable to solve the 'else' part where you have to show than if end value is greater than start value, then program have to print something, that you can see in the code

```
print("Enter start value")
sv = int(input())

print("Enter end value")
ev = int(input())

for i in range(sv,ev+1):
    if(i % 2 != 0):
         print(i)
    elif(sv > ev):
         print("Start value should be greater than end value")
```

Answer (score 1):

if start value is grater then end value than for loop won't run so just put condition above like this

```
print("Enter start value")
sv = int(input())

print("Enter end value")
ev = int(input())
if (sv > ev):
    print("Start value should be less than end value")

for i in range(sv,ev+1):
    if(i % 2 != 0):
         print(i)
```

Answer (score 1):

If `ev+1` is smaller than `sv` then `range(sv, ev+1)` becomes an empty iterator and the `for` loop runs ZERO times.

You should move the check before the for-loop:

```
if (sv > ev):
    print("Start value should be greater than end value")
else:
    for i in range(sv,ev+1):
        if(i % 2 != 0):
            print(i)
```

To demo how `range()` works:

```
>>> list(range(1,4))
[1, 2, 3]
>>> list(range(4,1))
[]
>>> list(range(4,1,-1))
[4, 3, 2]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def oddNumbers(l, r):
    return list(range(l if l % 2 else l + 1, r + 1, 2))

start = int(input("Enter the start of range: "))
end = int(input("Enter the end of range: "))
if (start> end):
    print("Start value should be greater than end value")

print(oddNumbers(start,end))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can let the range function step by two on its own so you don't need to check divisibility by 2 on every iteration.  Simply make sure you start at the appropriate even number:

```
for i in range(sv+sv%2,ev+1,2):
    print(i)
```